# Call onFinish as button outside timer

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to call onFinish with outComeButton:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OutCome0 extends Activity {
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
    public TextView text;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
    EditText editTime1;
    Button startButton;

    /*Skip go straight to an outcome 
     * To Do Instead of having two sets of the same shit, call onFinish here.*/
         public void outComeButton(View v){
             ;
         };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_out_come0);
        editTime1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTime1);     
        startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            /*Start the timer */
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get the name from edittext and storing into string variable
                long timeVal = Long.parseLong(editTime1.getText().toString());
                /* the keyboard wasen't auto hiding. below three lines force it closed.*/
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                          Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(startButton.getWindowToken(), 0);

                if (!timerHasStarted) {
                    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(timeVal * 1000 * 60, interval);
                    text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(timeVal / 1000));
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    timerHasStarted = true;
                    startButton.setText("STOP");
                } else {
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    timerHasStarted = false;
                    startButton.setText("RESTART");
                }
            }
            class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
              public MyCountDownTimer(long timeVal, long interval) {
               super(timeVal, interval);
              }

             public void outComeButton(View v){
                 this.onFinish();
             };
              /* Converts tick time to 00:00 need to fix so that 1 min 30 seconds is 01:30 instead of 01:3
               * Currently hidden, maybe though do somthing with onTick later.*/              
              @Override
              public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              /* text.setText(""+String.format("%d:%d", 
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - 
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))
                    ));*/
              }

              @Override
              /* Finish event  Need to make it so that videos can be played if solo mode.*/
              public void onFinish() {
                  int num;
                  String outCome = "";
                  for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
                      num = (int) (Math.random() * 100) % 4;

                      switch (num) {
                      case 0:
                      case 1:
                          outCome = "Outcome1";
                          break;
                      case 2:
                          outCome = "outcome2";
                          break;
                      case 3:
                          outCome = "outcome3";
                          break;
                 }
                    text.setText(outCome);
             }
               Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
               // Vibrate for 5 seconds
               v.vibrate(5000);
              }
             }
            });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.out_come0, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

It complains saying the method outComeButton is never used locally. Is there an issue with my XML or did I put the button in the wrong place?

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/outComeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="outComeButton"
        android:text="@string/outComeButton" />
```

Also the error I get from logcat when I try and hit the button:

```
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method outComeButton(View) in the activity class com.example.timer.OutCome0 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'outComeButton'
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2131)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: outComeButton
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2124)
01-19 01:02:50.507: E/AndroidRuntime(379):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: If you specify a listener in your layout XML file with `android:onClick` the method (in code) MUST have a signature which includes a `View` as a parameter, e.g., `public void outComeButton(View v)`.

Comment: I edited it and I get the same issue...

Comment: Your definition of your `outComeButton` is in the same XML layout file which is used by the `Activity` where you define the method? Correct?

Comment: Change button id and string name then try. And dont forget to make changes in activity.

Comment: I changed them, still nothing.

Comment: post your complete activity code.

Comment: Posted the whole activity.

Answer (score 0):

the onClick you're pointing to in the XML layout file must be part of the Activity that's inflating the view with the button.

extract the method out to the class and finish the timer from there, and everything should work just fine.

in general, declaring the onClick in the XML is bad practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The "never used locally" warning comes from the second `outComeButton()` method inside the anonymous `OnClickListener` inner class.

Defining an `onClick` listener in XML requires that it is found in the activity. If you removed or commented out the first, activity-level `outComeButton()` method, that would explain the exception in the stacktrace.

Remove the inner `outComeButton()` and do what you want to get done in the activity-level method.